# Numbered list with text in same cell in excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, cell, numbered

I was wondering whether it is possible to make a numbered list with text in the same cell just like in MS Word:

1. Tom
2. Jack
3. Albert

My goal is to have automatic numbering only while being able freely to input any text next to it by clicking the cell.

Basically, exactly like MS Word. Press enter -> next line, next number -> add text.

I tried **concatenate** function, but this is rather cumbersome.

Comment: You can't do it in a plain cell, but if you fit a text box to a cell then it would work.

Comment: it will be possible using VBA